# mysql select rows by consecutive date

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table of available date blocks (7 days in my case) which may or may not be consecutive:

```
start_date    end_date    booked    id    room_id

2012-07-14    2012-07-21    0       1        6
2012-07-21    2012-07-28    0       2        6
2012-07-28    2012-08-04    1       3        6
2012-08-04    2012-08-11    0       4        6
```

What I'd like to do is be able to get a result set that gives me one row per X weeks of consecutive unbooked dates, within a date range.

So, for 2 week blocks starting on the 14th of July and using the above table data, I would expect the following:

```
start_date    end_date    booked
2012-07-14    2012-07-28    0
```

The second block of 2 weeks would not be returned as one of the component weeks is booked.

Here are a few ideas I've tried already:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(start_date) AS start_date_min,
    MAX(end_date) AS end_date_max,
    CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS CHAR) AS ids,
    SUM(booked) AS booked
FROM 
    available_dates
WHERE
    (start_date>=20120714 AND end_date<=DATE_ADD(20120714, INTERVAL 14 DAY))
GROUP BY
    room_id
HAVING
    end_date_max=DATE_ADD(20120714, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

This gets me part of the way, however doesn't get me the *consecutive* results - that is the important part. It also only returns a single result (probably because of the HAVING clause) when I widen the test data.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can't really do this with a simple query - you need to compare ACROSS rows, which means you'll have to do some self-joins, and probably need a self-join for every extra level of consecutive blocks you need to chain together. This'd get ugly very fast.

Comment: I kind of think this is impossible to achieve with pure mysql. Oracle would provide some neat tricks for this... but this would definetly not be standard.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts, shame there isn't an easier way to do this. I think I'll give PHP a shot, get the dates from the DB and loop through them - I've exhausted my limited SQL knowledge unfortunately :(

Comment: @jammypeach I'm not clear, do you want to have the last 14 days consecutive, order by, right?

Comment: @jcho360 not exactly - more like an exclusive condition so that if the weeks are not one after the other, i.e start dates are more than 14 days apart, then they would not be in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a calendar or a  `numbers` table:

```
CREATE TABLE num
( i INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (i)
) ;

INSERT INTO num 
  (i) 
VALUES
  (0), (1), (2), ..., (1000) ;
```

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT 
    avail.room_id,
    MIN(avail.start_date) AS start_date_min,
    MAX(avail.end_date) AS end_date_max,
    CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(avail.id) AS CHAR) AS ids,
    SUM(avail.booked) AS booked
FROM 
    available_dates AS avail
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT DATE('2012-07-14') AS start_date_check
           , 52                 AS max_week_check
    ) AS param
  JOIN
    num
      ON  avail.start_date = param.start_date_check + INTERVAL num.i WEEK
      AND num.i < param.max_week_check
WHERE
    avail.booked = 0
GROUP BY
    avail.room_id,
    ( num.i / 2 )        
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

You could also have this:

```
WHERE
    1 =1                         --- no WHERE condition
GROUP BY
    avail.room_id,
    ( num.i / 2 )        
HAVING                           --- and optionally
    SUM(avail.booked) = 0        --- this
```

Comment: how many rows would I need / want in `num` for this to work, and would it be permanent? i.e would I need to add more rows to `num` at some point down the line?

Comment: Will you need to be searching for periods longer than 1000 weeks? I have a number table with 10K or 100K rows in some of my dbs. You add it once and just remove permissions to alter/update/insert/delete from everyone.

Comment: ah I get it now. I'll only need 4 max (atleast for today) so no worries :). Just testing now, will be back to accept if all goes well - thanks

Comment: Note: the query assumes that all your blocks are 7-days long.

Comment: this did the trick, many thanks. never would have figured this out on my own :)